# angular and google analytics integration => ga is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, analytics

I'm doing an angular(4) application, but i got a problem integrating google analytics.
I'm currently to add google analytics to my single page web application. But when I try to retrieve the ga function to send the new url it seems that it don't find the function.

This is the code I got:

index.hbs

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'My-key', 'auto');
</script>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {WindowRef} from "./social/windowRef";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    user: User;
    private currentRoute: string;

    constructor(private misc: MiscService, public router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                console.log(event.urlAfterRedirects);
                WindowRef.get().ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
                WindowRef.get().ga('send', 'pageview');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

windowRef.ts

```
export class WindowRef{
    public static get(): any{
        console.log(window);
        return window;
    }
}
```

I got this error: `ERROR TypeError: windowRef_1.WindowRef.get(...).ga is not a function`

When I do `console.log(WindowRef.get());` I can see in the window the ga function but it still display the previous error when I try to use it.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5Ye.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlN1.png)

I don't really understand I used this method to retrieve the stripe function and it worked pretty well.

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had a similar problem trying to integrate Google Analytics into my Angular 4 App.

What did the trick for me was to move the google analytics code from the AppComponent's constructor to the [**ngAfterViewInit()**](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook to ensure that the view is fully initialized first.

Here's the code I got:

**index.html (same as you):**

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'some code', 'auto');
</script>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';

// declare google analytics
declare const ga: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
              private router: Router) {}


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      // I check for isPlatformBrowser here because I'm using Angular Universal, you may not need it
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        console.log(ga); // Just to make sure it's actually the ga function
        ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you as well. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it says that ga is not defined. Do I have to send it somehow to the app.component.ts ?

Comment: if ( typeof window != 'undefined' )

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I didn't put the googleAnalytics script before the body, it was after. Now it works well. thanks to @WeissDev, it put me on the way when I saw that `ga` wasn't defined despite being in the `window` (weird). Anyway his solution works well too.

Answer (score 2):

If @WeissDev answer don't work for you use setInterval to make sure its ready before using it.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initGoogleAnalyticsPageView()
  }

  private initGoogleAnalyticsPageView() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if ((window as any).ga && (window as any).ga.getAll) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
          const ga = (window as any).ga
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            const tracker = ga.getAll()[0]
            tracker.set('page', event.urlAfterRedirects)
            tracker.send('pageview')
          }
        })
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    }, 50)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Analytics Google Website they say this:

> Copy the global site tag into the `<head>` section of your HTML. Or,
> if you use a website builder (e.g. WordPress, Shopify, etc), copy the
> global site tag into your website builder’s custom HTML field.

It needs to go into `<head>` tag.

Comment: If you are using Angular this aproach is not working because ANGULAR does not allow SCRIPT tags to be injected for SECURITY reasons. Follow this link: https://angular.io/guide/security